Fast and efficient ways to search very large JSON files for more than one matching keys?
Looking for the best way, whether it be a npm package or some kind of algorithm that would most efficiently search a 40mb+ size JSON file for several matching keys. For example let's say the JSON file has
{ name: "Test", age: 23, record_id: 2352352 }
and I would want to search the 20k+ objects in the JSON file for a match on any 2 of the 3 keys and values. I have to do this within a AWS Lambda function, so speed to cut down operation costs is ideal. What would be the best way to do this?
I have looked into past answers here on stack overflow but a large portion of them involved libraries that are no longer online. I considered a straight up for loop, but I can't imagine that is anywheres remotely efficient.
Thank you for your help!

Transform the data structure into something you don't have to search linearly. Like a database would do: make indexes.

The only efficient way is to replace the array of objects with an object whose keys are the values you want to search for. So instead of [{ name: "Test", age: 23, record_id: 2352352 }, ...] it should be {"Test": [{ name: "Test", age: 23, record_id: 2352352 }, ...], ...}.

But as a general rule, when you have this much data, flat files are not the appropriate technology. This is exactly what databases are for.

Thank you both; yeah i'd perfer to have used a database but the costs I think is what keeps us from not doing it :(

If the tool you chose means you can't actually do the work, then from a business case perspective the cost of doing that work anyway is infinite, with the conclusion being "we can easily do this is we want to invest in the right technology, and otherwise this isn't happening" =) You can see if jq gets you a bit more performance (e.g. https://www.ubertechblog.com/2021/01/using-jq-in-aws-lambda-custom-runtime-via-aws-lambda-layer.html) but you really want a database.

There are free/inexpensive databases like SQLite and MySQL.

Change the way you get the results of your query from the database
